# Convert asc to doc files

Tags: windows, gratis, document-converter

I have several files in .asc format. They contain text and images with markdown from github. I tried to open them with Microsoft office and then save them in doc, but I want the visual format of markdown and not the code.

For example, if I open the files, headers are like this

```
== Here is a header ==
```

But in visual the results is

```
Here is a header (with bold and big fonts)
```

So, I want a converter:

- free
- convert asc to doc
- keep the visual format and not the markdown format
- Operating system: Windows

Answer (score 5):

## [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

I haven't dealt with asc files but as long as it is a text based format and uses fairly standard Markdown format Pandoc will be able to process that fine.

It is very cross platform (on some systems for some outputs you will have to install extra stuff - ie Latex for PDF output on Windows).

It is command line only; full details on arguments [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html).

Yes it is free.